# Resolve user type in authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a simple application with two models, Client and Teacher that are connected by a OneToOne with the default Django User.

There is one login page in the application. Based on the user type, I want to redirect them to both /myaccount but show different templates.

Here is my code:

```
def user_login(request):
context_dict ={}

if request.method =='POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user= authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    #teacher flow
    if user.teacher:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            template = 'teacher_account.html'
            context_dict['teacher'] = user
            return render(request, template, context_dict)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled")
    #client flow
    elif user.client:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            template = "client_account.html"
            context_dict['client'] = user
            return render(request, template, context_dict)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled")

    else:
        print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied")
#GET Request
else:
    return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

It actually works (sort of, the redirect doesn't, but the login does) if it is a teacher. I've tried debugging and if the user is a client, for some reason the flow doesn't drop into the else if but just errors out. In the debugger I can see that the client object exists, but I am getting the error RelatedObjectDoesNotExist - User has no teacher. What am I doing wrong?

Django 1.7, Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user.client` is exists but `user.teacher` doesn't, so you get the error then you access this attribute in the `if user.teacher:` statement.

Replace it with the something like this:

```
if Teacher.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
    ...
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Any idea on why my render() is not working? I am trying to redirect to a separate template based on the user type logging in.

Comment: What do you mean by " render() is not working"? You get some error?

Comment: Instead of redirecting to the templates I set, like teacher_account.html, its redirecting me to just /

Comment: I don't see any redirects in your code.  Do you have non-standard middleware?